# Not all users can add Add-in to site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, sharepoint-addin, user-profile

I have a SP 2013 Add-in that all users must be able to add to sites.
The app have the scope `User Profiles` set to read. But the problem is that users that doesn't have the permission `full controll` cant add the app since they dont have have access to user profiles.

Only thing i found was this

> Apps that request rights for the User Profiles scope must be installed
>   by a tenant administrator

Is there a way to have regular users be able to add it anyway? 
Or is there any other thing I can do to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user has *full control* he will require approval from Tenant Administrator or Global Administrator to add in the app. If user is Site Collection Administrator they will still need approval from tenant administrator. If you want your users to be able to manage a single site you must give them at least full control over that site so they can add webparts or apps from sharepoint app store.

If you want users to be completely autonomous i.e not request for any approval you must give them *tenant administrator privileges* to be able to add apps which deal with user profiles.